# Ngrx all reselect selectors being run on single state slice change

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx, reselect

```
import { GlobalState } from './app.reducer';
import * as App from './app.actions';

import { AppState } from './appstate';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

//Global Reducer State
export interface GlobalState {
  search: SearchState;
}

//This is based on GlobalState
export const reducers = {
  search: reducer
}


//Sub Search State
export interface SearchState {
    values: string[];
    numbers: number[];
}

export const initialSearchState : SearchState = {
    values:[],
    numbers:[]
}


export function reducer(state = initialSearchState, action: App.Actions): SearchState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case App.ActionTypes.ADD_VALUE: {
      return {
        values: [...state.values, action.payload],
        numbers: state.numbers
      };
    }
    case App.ActionTypes.ADD_NUMBER: {
      return {
        values: state.values,
        numbers: [...state.numbers, action.payload]
      };
    }
  }

  return state;
}


export const getValues = (state: SearchState) => {
  //<<DEBUG 1>>
  return state.values;
}
export const getNumbers = (state: SearchState) => {
  //<<DEBUG 2>>
  return state.numbers;
}


export const getGlobalState = (state: GlobalState) => state.search;
export const getSearchValues = createSelector(getGlobalState, getValues);
export const getSearchNumbers = createSelector(getGlobalState, getNumbers);
```

And in the component I have run the following two selectors

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public store: Store<GlobalState>) {
    this.values = this.store.select(getSearchValues);
    this.numbers = this.store.select(getSearchNumbers);
  }
```

The issue is each time `App.ActionTypes.ADD_VALUE` action is called to ONLY update `values` then BOTH the selectors `getSearchValues` (for `values`) and `getSearchNumbers` (for `numbers`) are called. (If you put a debug point in `//<<DEBUG 1>>` and `//<<DEBUG 2>>` both will be reached).

Is it possible to have only the selectors related to the changed slice be run instead of all selectors, as if there are 40 selectors every selector will be run each time there is a change to a single part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getSearchValues` and `getSearchNumbers` selectors share the same input - `state.search` - and it's the selector input that's used to determine whether reselect's memoized selection can be used.

As the input to `getSearchNumbers` changes when an `ADD_VALUE` action is dispatched, that selector called as well as `getSearchValues`.

Comment: As per your first sentence what would you suggest for this use case? or is it not possible.

According to your second sentence you mean I recreate the whole state for when the value is added (since state shouldnt be mutable)? Since the state should be IMMUTABLE so unrelated parts of the state would also be "recreated" how would you suggest to handling this

Comment: The selector's are trivial, so there's nothing you need to do. Your point about immutability is why reselect exists - adding a value will see `state` and `state.search` changed, too, as they will be new instances. However, if you had `state.other`, that would not change - so any reselect-created selector using that as an input would return the memoized result. `state.search.numbers` will be the same array instance, but `getSearchNumbers` needs to run because its input - `state.search` - is a different instance.